# Create a SoftLayer virtual guest on a specific subnet

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Recently I noticed the SoftLayer UI has changed and part of that change was the ability to specify a subnet on a VLAN when ordering a virtual guest.

Has this support been implemented in the REST API json payload when specifying primaryNetworkComponent and primaryBackendNetworkComponent parameters to create a virtual guest?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Currently It's possible to set the subnets, you should define "primarySubnet" inside of "networkVlan" property, here a Rest example:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "orderContainers":[  
            {  
               "hardware":[  
                  {  
                     "hostname":"testhost",
                     "domain":"softlayer.com",
                     "primaryBackendNetworkComponent":  
                        {  
                           "networkVlanId":971077,
                           "networkVlan":{  
                              "primarySubnet":{  
                                 "id":225652
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ,
                     "primaryNetworkComponent":  
                        {  
                           "networkVlanId":971075,
                           "networkVlan":{  
                              "primarySubnet":{  
                                 "id":233232
                              }
                           }
                        }

                  }
               ],
               "location":"DALLAS05",
               "quantity":1,
               "packageId":46,
               "prices":[  
                  {  
                     "id":1640
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":1644
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":1857
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":1639
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":50367
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":273
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":2302
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":55
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":58
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":420
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":418
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":21
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":57
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":905
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey** and the values for: **networkVlanId** and **primarySubnet >> id** with your own information

Comment: If I don't have a subnet specification, Can I code `"primaryNetworkComponent":  
                        {  
                           "networkVlanId":971075

Comment: Got caught in 5 minute timeout to edit comment.  If I don't have a subnet specification, Can I code `"primaryNetworkComponent":  
                        {  
                           "networkVlanId":971075 },`         or do I specify `"primaryNetworkComponent" : {
            "networkVlan" : {
                "id": 971075
            }
         },`    or does either work if no subnet is specified?

Comment: Both cases should work, it is not necessary to specify the subnet, you can only define the vlan if you wish.

Comment: I tried to use virtualGuests instead of hardware and got error.   '_content' => '{"error":"The property \'networkVlanId\' is not valid for \'SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Network_Component\'.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}',       Is networkVlanId only valid for hardwre?

Comment: Went back to format `"networkVlan":{  "id" : 971075,
                              "primarySubnet":{  
                                 "id":233232
                              }
                           }

Comment: The **networkVlanId** is not a property from [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Network_Component](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Network_Component) object, in this case, I recommend to use hardware object to define vlans.