# Subnet error while ordering baremetal server

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I use the following json parameters to order a Baremetal server

```
`{
    "parameters": [
        {
            "location": "449494",
            "packageId": 257,
            "hardware": [
                {
                    "hostname": "BMtest1",
                    "domain": "domain.com",
                    "primaryBackendNetworkComponent": {
                        "networkVlanId": "1229225"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "prices": [
                {
                    "id": "49515"
                },
                {
                    "id": "50357"
                },
                {
                    "id": "49759"
                },
                {
                    "id": "876"
                },
                {
                    "id": "55"
                },
                {
                    "id": "57"
                },
                {
                    "id": "175791"
                },
                {
                    "id": "273"
                },
                {
                    "id": "21"
                },
                {
                    "id": "49495"
                },
                {
                    "id": "906"
                },
                {
                    "id": "418"
                },
                {
                    "id": "420"
                },
                {
                    "id": "58"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}`
```

the verifyOrder call is success and returns the details.
But when I do place order it gives the following error:
`{"error":"A valid subnet id must be provided.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}`

How can I correct this error. Please let me know if some additional parameters are to be added.

Comment: I was able to make this work by adding the following json parameter
`"hardware": [
    {
     "hostname": "BMtest1",
     "domain": "domain.com",
     "primaryBackendNetworkComponent": {
      "networkVlanId": 1229225,
      "networkVlan": {
       "id": 1229225,
       "primarySubnetId": 1208347,
       "vlanNumber": 2072
      }
     }
    }
   ],`

Comment: Something weird, but here a reference: [Create a SoftLayer virtual guest on a specific subnet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592080/create-a-softlayer-virtual-guest-on-a-specific-subnet)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the **"1229225"** without **quotes**:

> "networkVlanId": 1229225

Try this:

```
{
    "parameters": [
        {
            "location": "449494",
            "packageId": 257,
            "hardware": [
                {
                    "hostname": "BMtest1",
                    "domain": "domain.com",
                    "primaryBackendNetworkComponent": {
                        "networkVlanId": 1229225
                    }
                }
            ],
            "prices": [
                {
                    "id": "49515"
                },
                {
                    "id": "50357"
                },
                {
                    "id": "49759"
                },
                {
                    "id": "876"
                },
                {
                    "id": "55"
                },
                {
                    "id": "57"
                },
                {
                    "id": "175791"
                },
                {
                    "id": "273"
                },
                {
                    "id": "21"
                },
                {
                    "id": "49495"
                },
                {
                    "id": "906"
                },
                {
                    "id": "418"
                },
                {
                    "id": "420"
                },
                {
                    "id": "58"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}`
```