# REST: use SoftLayer_Hardware::createObject instead of SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to order two bare metal servers
I did it via REST api: SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
with the following payload.

```
 "useHourlyPricing": true,
          "quantity": 2,
          "location": 448994,
          "packageId": 200,
          "presetId": 95,
          "prices": [
            {
              "id": 36365
            },
            {
              "id": 52795
            },
            {
              "id": 1800
            },
            {
              "id": 21
            },
            {
              "id": 906
            },
            {
              "id": 420
            },
            {
              "id": 418
            }
          ]
```

However, the servers created with separate vLANs.
How to make the order of multiple servers share the same vLANs?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, i**t's not possible to define VLANS for package 200 (Fast Servers)**, it means that you will not be able to do this through [SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/createObject)

You will be able to set VLANS (even subnets), if you try with a different package for Bare Metal Servers.

Just in case, here an example to order a Server defining the vlans and subnets (This is for VSI, but the same idea should be applied for Bare Metal Servers)

- [Create a SoftLayer virtual guest on a specific subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592080/create-a-softlayer-virtual-guest-on-a-specific-subnet)

**Note**: [SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/createObject) method allows to order packages 50 and 200 (package 200 when you set preset configuration), in case that you wish to order package 50 (without preset config), you will be able to set vlans and subnets.

---

> **Updated**

---

### Retrieve Vlans - Subnets available based on Package and Location

The vlans should belong in the same datacenter in which you wish to place the order, to get vlan and subnets (public/private) information available for the package and location, you can try the following request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/getVlans

Method: Post

{
  "parameters": 
   [
       448994, 50
   ]
}
```

**Replace:** $user and $apiKey with you own information. Also **448994 refers to locationId and 50 refers to packageId**, replace them with the values that you wish

**References:**
 - [SoftLayer_Product_Order::getVlans](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/getVlans)

Comment: thanks. so i should put the following json in my payload. so where i should find the networkVlanId , primarySubnet id, and primarySubnet id? where does it comes from?

Comment: i tried the example in the link provide. and got the error {
  "error": "Could not obtain network VLAN with id #971077.",
  "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
} ; any idea?

Comment: Probably there is not any vlan with that identifier. Review the **Updated** section in my answer, that request will help to retrieve vlans and subnets for a specific package and location

Comment: thanks. so if i want to order 3 bare metal servers that share the same pub/private vlan; first, i can order one server which will have pub/priv vlans. i can get the vlan/subnet ids via api SoftLayer_Account/Hardware?objectMask=mask[networkVlans[networkSpace,primarySubnets]; then i can order the other 2 servers using the vlan/subnet ids in the order payload. then the 3 servers will have the same vlan/subnet. correct?

Comment: Yep, that's make sense and works. Another way, would be using script that I provided before to get Vlans and Subnets available (with free slots), in which you need to check that the subnet has enough slots (in this case 3), and then you can place the three orders at once time.

Comment: Hi Ruber, i can get any vlans in the list returned by SoftLayer_Product_Order/getVlans if they have more than 3 slots of the subnet, right?

Comment: Yes, that's useful for your requirements, you won't have troubles to provision the three servers inside that vlan/subnet