# How can I filter the list of VLANs to just get ones valid for virtual guest orders?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to filter the list of VLANs on an account so that I only list the VLANs which can be used to order a Virtual Guest. I am using Softlayer_Account_Service.getNetworkVlans().

What do I need to filter by? It is just filtering for networkVlans.type.keyName = STANDARD?

I’m trying to avoid being able to hit this error when I select a VLAN from my list: `SoftLayer_Exception_Public: The frontend VLAN #xxxxxxx is not a standard VLAN. (HTTP 500)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get available vlans for ordering, see **Retrieve Vlans - Subnets available based on Package and Location** section on the below link:

- [REST: use SoftLayer_Hardware::createObject instead of SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964159/rest-use-softlayer-hardwarecreateobject-instead-of-softlayer-product-orderp/42965025#42965025)

For Vsi's, should be:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/getVlans

Method: Post

{
  "parameters": 
   [
       448994, 46
   ]
}
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey** and **448994** with the location identifier that you would like to order

**To get datacenter identifiers:**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters

Method: Get
```

---

### To get STANDARD vlans from specific location

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans?objectMask=mask[type,primaryRouter[datacenter]]&objectFilter={"networkVlans":{"type":{"keyName":{"operation":"STANDARD"}}, "primaryRouter":{"datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"wdc01"}}}}}

Method: Get
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey** and **wdc01** with the location that you would like to get the vlans

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can I still use the standard SL filter mechanism on this request? E.g. to get just the VLANs on a particular primary router, or to filter by datacenter name e.g. mex01 rather than having to use the location ID? I had several different filters in place when I was using the AccountService.getNetworkVlans - it would be a shame if I had to lose those by switching to this API.

Comment: Well, in my opinion I tried using many filters to get the exactly vlans that UI displays for VLANs at the moment to place an order, but I didn't get same result like Portal, you can try, but I believe the best bet is: [SoftLayer_Product_Order::getVlans](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/getVlans) for ordering

Comment: I added in my answer: **To get STANDARD vlans from specific location** section, that request will help to retrieve **STANDARD vlans from a specific location**

Comment: To clarify, are you confirming that the STANDARD vlans approach should give me the same result as the portal, so I could continue to use the account service?

Comment: As I told you before, if your purpose is to get vlans for ordering, you must use: **SoftLayer_Product_Order::getVlans** method

Comment: In that case, my previous question still remains - is it possible to use normal SoftLayer object masks and filters with SoftLayer_Product_Order::getVlans ? I tried to use this filter, but it doesn't seem to work - is there a correct form for this filter? "{"vlans":{"primaryRouter":{"datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"mex01"}}}}}"
(As above, our current flow requires datacenter names, not location IDs, so sending the location ID in the payload doesn't help me)

Comment: No, it's not possible because the **SoftLayer_Product_Order::getVlans** will return the vlans for a specific location. There is not another way to return the same result that Portal shows for available vlans/subnets in order's form.