# Softlayer API Hardware: RAM-related Error when calling verifyOrder() for Bare Metal

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to do a dry-run for ordering a bare metal server using the Softlayer python API following the instructions here: http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/ordering-bare-metal-servers-using-softlayer-api and leveraging the sample code provided (https://gist.github.com/bmpotter/27913e92e9ff7b6b0c54).  However, I keep getting this exception when doing a orderVerify():

SoftLayer_Exception_Public: The price for 64 GB RAM (#154399) is not valid for location dal10.

Here is price array I use for package 253:

```
prices = [
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'server', 'INTEL_XEON_2620_2_40')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'os', 'OS_UBUNTU_14_04_LTS_TRUSTY_TAHR_64_BIT')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'ram', 'RAM_64_GB_DDR3_1333_REG_2')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'disk_controller', 'DISK_CONTROLLER_RAID_1')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'disk0', 'HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'disk1', 'HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'disk2', 'HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'disk3', 'HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'port_speed', '10_GBPS_REDUNDANT_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'power_supply', 'REDUNDANT_POWER_SUPPLY')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'bandwidth', 'BANDWIDTH_0_GB')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'pri_ip_addresses', '1_IP_ADDRESS')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'remote_management', 'REBOOT_KVM_OVER_IP')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'vpn_management', 'UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'monitoring', 'MONITORING_HOST_PING_AND_TCP_SERVICE')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'notification', 'NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'response', 'AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'vulnerability_scanner', 'NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING')},
]
```

And the order info:

```
{'hardware': [{'domain': 'my.domain.com',
           'hostname': 'myHost'}],
 'location': 1441195,
 'packageId': 253,
 'prices': [{'id': 50635},
        {'id': 37652},
        {'id': 154399},
        {'id': 141957},
        {'id': 49811},
        {'id': 49811},
        {'id': 49811},
        {'id': 49811},
        {'id': 35685},
        {'id': 50223},
        {'id': 35963},
        {'id': 34807},
        {'id': 25014},
        {'id': 33483},
        {'id': 34241},
        {'id': 32500},
        {'id': 32627},
        {'id': 35310}],
 'quantity': 1}
```

I checked and RAM_64_GB_DDR3_1333_REG_2 is in the output of getOrderItemsDict().  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake with price: 154399, it is not valid for Dallas 10 datacenter (1441195), to get more information you can review the below link:

[Location-based Pricing and You](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you)

You can try changing this price **49427**(is a standard price which is valid for any datacenter) instead of 154399 in the order, for RAM_64_GB_DDR3_1333_REG_2

---

### Retrieve packages (prices and locations) which contain specific items

```
"""
This script searches packages with its prices and locations according 
to items sent (it's necessary to send the item's keyName, it's possible 
to send more than one item to search)

Important links:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getActivePackages
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
from prettytable import PrettyTable

# Define your username and apiKey
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Items to search
items = ['INTEL_XEON_2620_2_40',
         'OS_UBUNTU_14_04_LTS_TRUSTY_TAHR_64_BIT',
         'RAM_64_GB_DDR3_1333_REG_2',
         'DISK_CONTROLLER_RAID_1',
         'HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2',
         'HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2',
         'HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2',
         'HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2',
         '10_GBPS_REDUNDANT_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS',
         'REDUNDANT_POWER_SUPPLY',
         'BANDWIDTH_0_GB',
         '1_IP_ADDRESS',
         'REBOOT_KVM_OVER_IP',
         'UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT',
         'MONITORING_HOST_PING_AND_TCP_SERVICE',
         'NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET',
         'AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION',
         'NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING']

# Declaring the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

# Declaring Account and Package services
accountService = client['SoftLayer_Account']
packageService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package']

# objectFilter to get standard prices
objectFilter = {"itemPrices":{"locationGroupId":{"operation":"is null"}}}

# Counting the items
countItems = len(items)

try:
    packages = accountService.getActivePackages()
    for package in packages:
        itemsDisplay = ''
        pricesDisplay = ''
        prices = packageService.getItemPrices(id=package['id'], filter=objectFilter)
        count = 0
        for item in items:
            for price in prices:
                if price['item']['keyName'] == item:
                    itemsDisplay += str("%s\n" % price['item']['keyName'])
                    pricesDisplay += str("%s\n" % price['id'])
                    count = count + 1
        if count == countItems:
            table = PrettyTable(["PackageId", "Item(s)", "Price(s)", "Location(s)"])
            locations = packageService.getRegions(id=package['id'])
            locationDisplay = ''
            for location in locations:
                locationDisplay += str("Id: %s (%s)\n" % (location['location']['location']['id'], location['location']['location']['longName']))
            table.add_row([package['id'], itemsDisplay, pricesDisplay, locationDisplay])
            print(table)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print(('Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString)))
```

---

### Setting VLANS

```
"hardware": [  
   {  
      "hostname":"testhost",
      "domain":"softlayer.com",
      "primaryBackendNetworkComponent":{  
         "networkVlanId":971077
      },
      "primaryNetworkComponent":{  
         "networkVlanId":971075
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  Per the comment in the sample code I use, it should return the right item id:

Comment: Though something I'm still wondering is, I looked thru the list and only found these options for RAM:  RAM_128_GB_DDR3_1333_REG_2,  RAM_256_GB_DDR3_1333_REG_2, RAM_512_GB_DDR4_2133_ECC_REG, RAM_64_GB_DDR3_1333_REG_2.  If only 16 GB of RAM is needed, what option should be used?

Comment: The minimum option for this kind of servers is 64 GB RAM, you need to chose another package if you would like to order a server with 16 GB RAM

Comment: Thanks that works.  So the next hurdle for me is to ensure all new servers are in the same Vlan.  I've looked around and noticed from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146080/how-can-i-filter-the-list-of-vlans-to-just-get-ones-valid-for-virtual-guest-orde/44146385#44146385 to use https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/getVlans to get the Vlans.  However, I tried with the Chrome poster REST client and always get {"privateVlans":[],"publicVlans":[]} with a 200 return code, tried different package/location same result.  Any ideas?

Comment: It means that you don't have any vlan purchased in that datacenter, but it is not the problem, if you don't have any vlan in there, SoftLayer will provide one without any charge.

Comment: Putting everything together, our typical order is 5 servers with the following items: INTEL_XEON_2650_2_30-dup
OS_UBUNTU_14_04_LTS_TRUSTY_TAHR_64_BIT
RAM_64_GB_DDR3_1333_REG_2
DISK_CONTROLLER_RAID
HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2
HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2
HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2
10_GBPS_REDUNDANT_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS
REDUNDANT_POWER_SUPPLY
BANDWIDTH_0_GB
1_IP_ADDRESS
REBOOT_KVM_OVER_IP
UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT
MONITORING_HOST_PING_AND_TCP_SERVICE
NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET
AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION
NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING

Comment: From experimenting with SL API, it seems not all packages have those items and not all locations/datacenters have all the packages.   Another thing is all 5 servers need to be on the same Vlan.  So is there any script/tool to help determine which package and location I can use to place the order with that requirement?  Pretty sure other customers would have the same need.  Figure I can crawl thru all the packages/location/Vlans to check but that would be very inefficient imho.

Comment: Let me check if I can create something to help with it

Comment: so while waiting for what you come up with, I explore another option; the REST  API approach : https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/createObject.  I found a preset keyName that’s closest to what we need D2620V4_64GB_2X1TB_SATA_RAID_1 (running of space so will post the payload I use in the next comment).  However, I'm getting a 500 Internal server error: {"error":"VLANs may not be specified for Bare Metal Server configurations.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}
The doc clearly mentions we can specify Vlan, not sure what’s going on.

Comment: Here is the payload I use:
{
  "parameters": [
  { 
    "hostname": "foobar", 
    "domain": "x.y.z.net", 
    "privateNetworkOnlyFlag":true,
   "hourlyBillingFlag": false, 
   "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "UBUNTU_14_64" ,
   "primaryNetworkComponent": { "networkVlan": { "id": 1307849 }},
   "datacenter": {"name": "dal10"},
   "fixedConfigurationPreset": {"keyName": "D2620V4_64GB_2X1TB_SATA_RAID_1"},
   "networkComponents": [{"maxSpeed": 1000}],
             "sshKeys":[{“id”: #####}]
  } 
 ]
}

Comment: Since you are ordering a preset configuration, this uses the package: 200 which is fast provisioning servers, unfortunately it's not possible to set vlans for this kind of servers

Comment: Review the script that I attached in **Retrieve packages (prices and locations) which contain specific items** section in my last answer. I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Ruber.  With your help was able to put together a working script.

Comment: hi @Ruber ... So I ran the script a couple of times ordering 5 BM servers each time and it worked both times.  However, upon closer inspection  I noticed a couple of things are still NOT quite right.  1) even though I specified the same vlan ID for all; NOT all servers are on the same VLAN; 1st order: 2 on one and 3 on another, 2nd order: 1 on one and 4 on a different one.  2) incorrect disk configuration: WANTED : 4 RAID1 disks associated with 2 logical volumes and volume 2 not mounted GOT: 4 RAID disks with 2 logical volumes and both volumes mounted ... out of space, more details following

Comment: Using package 253 and the following items: INTEL_XEON_2620_2_40, OS_UBUNTU_14_04_LTS_TRUSTY_TAHR_64_BIT, RAM_64_GB_DDR3_1333_REG_2, DISK_CONTROLLER_RAID, HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2, HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2, HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2, HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2, 1_GBPS_REDUNDANT_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS, REDUNDANT_POWER_SUPPLY, BANDWIDTH_0_GB, 1_IP_ADDRESS, REBOOT_KVM_OVER_IP, UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT, MONITORING_HOST_PING_AND_TCP_SERVICE, NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET, AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION, NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING.  Will post the final order next

Comment: {'hardware': [{'domain': 'fool.bar.net', 'hostname': 'my-bm-server', 'networkVlans': [{'id': 1307849}]}],
 'location': 1441195,
 'packageId': 253,
 'prices': [{'id': 50635}, {'id': 37652}, {'id': 49427}, {'id': 141945}, {'id': 49811}, {'id': 49811}, {'id': 49811}, {'id': 49811}, {'id': 26723}, {'id': 50223}, {'id': 35963}, {'id': 34807}, {'id': 25014}, {'id': 33483}, {'id': 34241}, {'id': 32500}, {'id': 32627}, {'id': 35310}],
 'quantity': 1,
 'storageGroups': [{'arrayTypeId': 2, 'hardDrives': [0, 1], 'partitionTemplateId': 1}, {'arrayTypeId': 2, 'hardDrives': [2, 3]}]} ... using dal10 DC

Comment: As you can see I searched for a VLAN that has enough slots using the code you provided and specified its ID for all the servers: 1307849 ... however, when I looked on https://control.softlayer.com/devices# this is what I see:  4 of my servers are on VLAN # 909 with ID 1307855 and only one on VLAN # 908 with ID 1307849.  Any ideas how I can debug/fix the 2 remaining issues?

Comment: As I see, there is a mistake in your template to define VLANS, I added **Setting Vlans** section in my answer, see it, for more information

Comment: So is there a restriction/required relation between "primaryBackendNetworkComponent" and "primaryNetworkComponent"?  That is do they have to be on the same Vlan number or just in the same datacenter is fine?  Thanks.

Comment: **primaryBackendNetworkComponent (private vlan)** and **primaryNetworkComponent (public vlan)**, both vlans should belong to the datacenter in which you would like to place the order. You can configure both or just one according to your requirements. There is no any restriction

Comment: Thanks Ruber.  On the other listed issue: the 4 RAID1 disks (spare ones unmounted).  Would that be 'DISK_CONTROLLER_RAID' or 'DISK_CONTROLLER_RAID1'?  Also how do you specify for the spare disks (3) to be not mounted?  Any links to doc where these are explained would also be of great help.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, Please review this link: [Ordering RAID Through API](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/hansKristian/Ordering-RAID-through-API), let me know if you have any doubt about how to configure this